# How do I regex a name and an email out of the 3 major email clients in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I thought I had it figured out, but it appears that my regex still has quirks in it.  Basically I would like to use the same regex pattern to match the following major email clients (Gmail, Yahoo, and regular email):

```
"Brian Mang" <brian.mang@email.com>   -- Case1
Brian Mang (brian.mang@email.com)     -- Case2
<brian.mang@email.com>                -- Case3
brian.mang@email.com                  -- Case4
```

I had the following regex pattern:

```
/[\W"]*(?<name>.*?)[\"]*?\s*[<(](?<email>\w.*)[>)]/.match(contact)
```

and it works for all Cases 1-3, but I cant get it to pick up case 4, I tried messing around with it but cant figure it out cause it breaks the other cases.  Any idea what I need to change/modify to make my regex pick up all of the 4 cases?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
[\W"]*(?<name>.*?)[\"]*?\s*[<(]?(?<email>\S+@\S+)[>)]?
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vvvt)

I made the classes surrounding the address optional and changed the part that matches the email to `\S+@\S+` that means at least one non-whitespace followed by a `@` then at least one more non-whitespace character.

Since the above version matches the closing character also, you can restrict the part after the @ a bit more

```
[\W"]*(?<name>.*?)[\"]*?\s*[<(]?(?<email>\S+@[^\s>)]+)[>)]?
```

see it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?3003f)

Comment: Thanks @stema but it appears that the final puncuation >) still exist for Case1 & Case2 & Case4., for example: email brian.mang@email.com> has the punctuation at the end, i tried messing with it but cant figure out how to remove it?

Answer (score -1):

*Edit:* This one works for all four:

```
[\W"]*(?<name>.*?)[\"]*?\s*[<(]?(?<email>\S+@[^)>]+)[>)]?
```

Comment: This breaks Case1 and Case2 for matching the name and email:  For example   
    name=""  
    email="Brian Mang (brian.mang@email.com)"