# Regex invalid group error while using in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, jquery-validate

I have the following regex that checks for multiple types of email address inputs

```
[\W"]*(?<name>.*?)[\"]*?\s*[<(]?(?<email>\S+@[^\s>)]+)[>)]?
```

I got this off [How do I regex a name and an email out of the 3 major email clients in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244430/how-do-i-regex-a-name-and-an-email-out-of-the-3-major-email-clients-in-ruby)

The problem i am facing is that while using this in javascript i get an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: `/[\W"]*(?"<name>".*?)[\"]*?\s*[<(]?(?"<email>"\S+@[^\s>)]+)[>)]?/`: Invalid group "

I spent an entire day trying to fix this and i found out that the problem has something to do with **lookbehind** That javascript doesn't support

I'm very bad at regex expressions and need some advice. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

PS: I am trying to make this function to integrate it with jquery validate plugin

[Jquery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: The "<name>" and "<email>" parts of the regular expression look quite wrong to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript in browsers generally do not support named capture.

Named capture bits are these `(?<name>.*?)` and `(?<email>\S+@[^\s>)]+)`.

You can replace named capture with numbered capture groups, changing this:

```
[\W"]*(?<name>.*?)[\"]*?\s*[<(]?(?<email>\S+@[^\s>)]+)[>)]?
```

to this:

```
[\W"]*(.*?)[\"]*?\s*[<(]?(\S+@[^\s>)]+)[>)]?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

So in JavaScript it would look like this:

```
match = subject.match(/[\W"]*(.*?)[\"]*?\s*[<(]?(\S+@[^\s>)]+)[>)]?/i);
if (match != null) {
    // matched text: match[0]
    // match start: match.index
    // capturing group 1 (name): match[1]
    // capturing group 2 (email): match[2]
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Remember that capture groups might only be added if they capture something.

Comment: Thanks Dean, your suggestion worked like a charm! except for one tiny problem. this exp doesn't seem to check the end of the email for a .com or .org etc..

Comment: For actual validation of the email address I would refer you to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Answer (score 0):

There's no lookbehind as far as I can tell (it'd be something like this: `(?<=prefix)`)
But maybe the labeled matching is not supported (`(?"<name>"...)`). Try without that and reference the matches by their number:

```
/[\W"]*(.*?)[\"]*?\s*[<(]?(\S+@[^\s>)]+)[>)]?/
```

The name will be the first and the email is the second captured group